# How can I stop my script to overwrite existing files

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I am learning bash since 6 days I think I got some of the basics.

Anyway, for the wallpapers downloaded from Variety I've written two scripts. One of them moves downloaded photos older than 12 days to a folder and renames them all as "Aday 1,2,3..." and the other lets me select these and moves them to another folder and removes photos I didn't select. 1st script works just as I intended, my question is about the other

I think I should write the script down to better explain my problem

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
    #Move victors of 'Seçme-Eleme' to 'Kazananlar'
    cd /home/eurydice/Bulunur\ Bir\ Şeyler/Dosyamsılar/Seçme-Eleme
    echo "Select victors"
    read vct
        for i in $vct; do
        mv -i "Aday $i.png" /home/eurydice/"Bulunur Bir Şeyler"/Dosyamsılar/Kazananlar/"Bahar $RANDOM.png" ;
        mv -i "Aday $i.jpg" /home/eurydice/"Bulunur Bir Şeyler"/Dosyamsılar/Kazananlar/"Bahar $RANDOM.jpg" ;
    done
    #Now let's remove the rest
    rm /home/eurydice/Bulunur\ Bir\ Şeyler/Dosyamsılar/Seçme-Eleme/*
```

In this script I originally intended to define another variable (let's call this "n") and so did I with copying and changing the variable from the first script. It was something like that

```
for i in $vct; do
            n=1
            mv "Aday $i.png" /home/eurydice/"Bulunur Bir Şeyler"/Dosyamsılar/Kazananlar/"Bahar $n.png" ;
            mv "Aday $i.jpg" /home/eurydice/"Bulunur Bir Şeyler"/Dosyamsılar/Kazananlar/"Bahar $n.jpg" ;
            n=$((n+1))
        done
```

When I do that for the first time the script worked just as I intended. However, in my 2nd test run this script overwrote the files that already existed. I mean, for example in 1st run i had 5 files whose names are "Bahar 1,2,3,4,5" and the 2nd time I chose 3 files to add. I wanted their names to be "Bahar 6,7,8" but instead, my script made them the new 1,2 and 3. I tried many solutions and when I couldn't fix that I just assigned random numbers to them.

Is there a way to make this script work as I intended?

Comment: You need to set n=1 outside of the loop. At present it is inside and so n is 1 on every iteration..

Comment: Now I wrote it like `read vct
n=1
 for i in $vct; do
 mv -i "Aday $i.png" /home/eurydice/"Bulunur Bir Şeyler"/Dosyamsılar/Kazananlar/"Bahar $n.png" ;
 mv -i "Aday $i.jpg" /home/eurydice/"Bulunur Bir Şeyler"/Dosyamsılar/Kazananlar/"Bahar $n.jpg" ;
 done
n=$((n+1))` but this time it says `mv: overwrite '/home/eurydice/Bulunur Bir Şeyler/Dosyamsılar/Kazananlar/Bahar 1.jpg'?` for each file I choose.

Comment: You need to increase `n` within the loop, why did you take `n=$((n+1))` outside too?

Comment: Oh, I am a bit ignorant about the loops so I thought if n is outside, I should increase n outside too :( It worked now!

Comment: As an aside, hardcoding the paths inside your script makes it much less useful. Probably make it read the source and destination directories as command-line parameters, perhaps with a fallback to a default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command finds the biggest file name number amongst files in current directory. If no file is found, biggest number is assigned to 0.

```
biggest_number=$(ls -1 | sed -n 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\)\(\.[a-zA-Z]\+\)\?$/\1/p' | sort -r -g | head -n 1)

[[ ! -z "$biggest_number" ]] || biggest_number=0
```

The regex in `sed` command assumes that there is no digit in filenames before the trailing number intended for increment.

As soon as you have found the biggest number, you can use it to start your loop to prevent overwrites.

```
n=$((biggest_number+1))
```